# How do you determine the Big-O notation of a while loop?

Tags: big-o

Below is a binary search function.

```
int search(int a[], int v, int left, int right)
{
    while (right >= left)
    {
        int m = (left + right)/2;
        if (v == a[m]) 
            return m;
        if (v < a[m])
            right = m - 1;
        else left = m + 1;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

How do I determine the Big-O notation for this function?

Is this search function O(n) since the while loop is dependent on the value of *left*?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In each step, the range of values halves (roughly) - if you start with `right - left == 100`, then at the second step it will be 49, then 24, then 11 etc.

Assuming `n = right - left`, the complexity is O(log n). (It's dependent on the values of both right and left.)

Comment: Given the question starts 'This is a binary search...', unless the code is badly messed up, the answer is a no brainer.  Rightly accepted, IMO.

Comment: @Shane - Well clearly this person is learning about the notation. How does he know it is correct?

Comment: He justifies the answer with logic.

That being said, homework questions leave one with a bad taste.

Answer (score 8):

Jon Skeet already [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137923/how-do-you-determine-the-big-o-notation-of-a-while-loop/2137931#2137931) the question.

Here I show how we can solve it mathematically.

Since in each loop we halve the range, in the worst case we'll need `steps` iterations at most.
How do we calculate the `steps` number?

"Halving the range" can be expressed as: **range / 2<sup>steps</sup>**

We can continue halving until `range` becomes **1**.
So the equation is: **range / 2<sup>steps</sup> = 1**

Solution:
 **lg(range / 2<sup>steps</sup>) = lg(1)**
**lg(range) - steps*lg(2) = 0**

**steps = lg(range)**, where *lg* is the logarithm with base 2.